# IIS 8 set up existing folder as virtual

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-8

I'm adding code to an existing web site, where I would like to have the code in a new folder. The folder is already created, as I have build the application using Visual Studio (setting up a new folder for the site).

It works perfectly fine to view the .html files in the new directory, but it's not possible to reach the .aspx files. The error message is

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

And then I tested to add a new virtual folder, which worked fine. But I cannot figure out how to make an existing folder virtual? Is that possible?

As Visual Studio is rather grumpy when it comes to renaming / recreating web applications, I'd like to avoid doing that all over again.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide to make the problem more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7, you would need to change it in IIS Manager

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx

I haven't used IIS 8, but assume it would be about the same.

Comment: I just tried to do it like the instructions (thanks), but it only described how to create a new Virtual Directory, not to make an existing one virtual. The only thing I found applicable is how to edit the permissions, but it's already set up to allow basically everything.

Comment: You should be able to change a normal directory into a virtual directory.

Comment: OK, that's comforting. Now I only need to figure out HOW to do it :)

Comment: Check the link I posted.

Comment: Thanks for the input!